# Application is force closed on virtual device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, virtual-machine, genymotion, google-vr

Here is the live problem :

https://gfycat.com/WhimsicalDeliciousGoldfish

I'm using the Genymotion software to emulate the android device. The connection is a Bridged network through the Wi-Fi adapter.

The application is the .apk for the emulated Daydream controller, it should be connected to Unity to emulate a working Daydream controller.

What I would like to know, is how can I debug the force close here, and know what's going wrong. And possibly if anyone else ever ran through the same issue using apps that communicate through the network.

Answer (score 0):

This is what Google states in their official VR SDK documentation :

A physical Android device running Android 4.4 (KitKat) or higher.
[VR SDK Docs](https://developers.google.com/vr/android/get-started)